# Merge two list with some conditional

Tags: c#, selenium, foreach

I get data from a table but values show not easy to manipulate.

My HTML structure like:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <span>1</span>
          <span>0</span>
          <br>
          <span>
            <span>Good Luck</span>
            <img src="/App_Themes/Resources/img/icon_tick.gif" width="3" height="7">
          </span>
       </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>Nowaday<br></b>
        <p>hook<br>zp</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But when I tried to get data will be like:

`10Good LuckNowadayhookzp`

I was using this code:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lstTable = browser.FindElements(By.XPath("table/tbody/tr"));
foreach (IWebElement val in lstTable)
{
     ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lstTDElement = val.FindElements(By.XPath("td"));
     ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lstSpecialEle = 
                          val.FindElements(By.XPath("//td/span | //td/b | //td/p"));
}
```

It will create many rows (in a `<tr>` tag I found about 6000), and I don't know how to arrangement with correct columns.

Because each column, data can be null or have many values in this.

Current, I have `lstTDElement` contains two columns(in real: 10 columns).

And `lstSpecialEle` contains all data necessary. 
I was filter only get with: `[//td/span | //td/b | //td/p]`.

How to integrated `lstSpecialEle` to `lstTDElement` with rights columns. Using `foreach` with the condition?

**Edited:**

Typical, I will receive from `lstTDElement` is: `10Good LuckNowadayhookzp`.

`lstSpecialEle` will create many rows contains all values I need.

The problem is: I don't know how to arrange all rows from `lstSpecialEle` into a table.

My table has two `<tr>` tag; this means it has two columns. How to organise all values in `lstSpecialEle` correct to this columns.

It should be like:

```
     Num                       Time
1 0 Good Luck             Nowaday hookzp
```

As mentioned, data is dynamic, first `<tr>` or second `<tr>` can not have tag like `<span>`, or don't have tag `<b>`, etc (it just does not appear, no new `<tag>` added)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are finding element from root means using `//` in your xpath which will search for elements in the whole page while you need to search within the specific row element only so you should try with `.//` in your xpath which will search for elements only specific element context. So I think you should try as below which will gives you only desire elements list instead of large amount of elements list as below :

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lstTable = browser.FindElements(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr"));
foreach (IWebElement val in lstTable)
{
  ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lstSpecialEle = val.FindElements(By.XPath(".//td/span | .//td/b | .//td/p"));
}
```

**Edited1** : If your getting list of elements with the combination of null text you can filter it with null condition and get sublists which contains exact text as below :-

```
var FinalList = lstSpecialEle.Where(x=>x.Text != null).ToList();
```

**Edited2** :- if you want to merge all columns text list into Single list of string try as below :-

```
List<string> FinalList = new List <string>();
foreach (IWebElement val in lstTable)
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lstSpecialEle = val.FindElements(By.XPath(".//td/span | .//td/b | .//td/p"));

    var AllTextList = lstSpecialEle.Where(x=>x.Text != null).ToList().Select(El => El.Text).ToList();

     string AllText = String.Join(" ", AllTextList);

     FinalList.Add(AllText);       
}
Console.WriteLine(FinalList);
```

Now `FinalList` will contain all values separated by per row.

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Yes, I add `.` before XPath element and it limit from 6000 rows to 16 -> 30 rows. And data is dynamic, so I can't know exact number of `.//td/span` or `.//td/b`. Because can be at columns X don't have any data. Have any idea like insert special character at rows null. To do that, we need to know columns contains rows.

Comment: @VănLộc you means you have got the list with the combination of null and exact element which you want. Right??

Comment: @VănLộc if am I right you can simply filter it with null condition and get sublist. See updated answer. Hope it works...:)

Comment: can you see my updated question. I don't know when the element is visible.

Comment: I know it, but when filter it, how to add correctly in columns? I need to know exact each column, each row in columns is null. To compare with other List<>.

Comment: @VănLộc ok I have got your problem.. please find the solution with the updated answer...:)